# How to make a table share a sequence with another table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically I have a table1 with unique ids of features for a city, now I got a table2 for features for that country.

I need to create new ids for the country table (these need to share the same sequence as the city, so that the ids match when cross referencing tables)

How to make table2 have the same ids as table1 within that city and then new ids for features elsewhere? Essentially sharing the sequence

Edit: the tables are already created, how can i update table2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you manually create a sequence and assign that as the default value to the ID columns, then it works. But to reuse an existing value that would mean we'd have to create a trigger that assign an existing value or obtains a new from the shared sequence.

```
create sequence baz;

create table foo(id bigint default nextval('baz'), value text);

create table bar(id bigint default nextval('baz'), value date);

insert into foo (value) values ('Hello');
insert into bar (value) values (now());
insert into foo (value) values ('World');
insert into bar (value) values (now());

select 'foo', id, value::text from foo 
union all
select 'bar', id, value::text from bar
```

And the result is:

```
foo 1   Hello
bar 2   2018-10-29
foo 3   World
bar 4   2018-10-29
```

And as a bonus:

`drop sequence baz`

```
ERROR: cannot drop sequence baz because other objects depend on it
  Detail: 
    default for table foo column id depends on sequence baz
    default for table bar column id depends on sequence baz
  Hint: Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

Edit: If we can do post processing then this approach could be usedto assign values for the missing ID columns:

```
update bar
SET id = coalesce((select id from foo where bar.city_name = foo.city_name),nextval('baz'))
WHERE id is null
```

Comment: Not entirely what I needed but I guess you pointed me out to the correct answer. I'm currently running 

update table2 set id = (select nextval('table1_seq1')) where id is null

Comment: How about:
update bar
SET id = coalesce((select id from foo where bar.value::text = foo.value),nextval('baz'))
WHERE id is null

Comment: The ids from table1 are already filled out so no need for the coalesce query, thanks tho. will report back once it finishes :)

Comment: Ermmm so after 1100 mins..... my query update table2 set id = (select nextval('table1_seq1')) where id is null

it just turned every single row into id 12548435

Comment: because select nextval is evaluated only once I reckon. You should use this:
Update table2 set id = nextval('table1_seq1') where id is null

Answer (score 5):

if your tables are already created you must create a sequence

```
create sequence seq_city_country;
```

and then add the sequence to your ids with the following code

```
ALTER TABLE city ALTER COLUMN id_city SET DEFAULT nextval('seq_city_country');
ALTER TABLE country ALTER COLUMN id_country SET DEFAULT nextval('seq_city_country');
```

---

if your sequence is already created for table city by (sequence_c) you can use

```
  ALTER TABLE country ALTER COLUMN id_country SET DEFAULT nextval('sequence_c');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE shared_seq;

CREATE TABLE a (
   col1 bigint  DEFAULT nextval('shared_seq'),
   ...
);

CREATE TABLE b (
   col1 bigint  DEFAULT nextval('shared_seq'),
   ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like very good (or even possible) database design.  Instead, I suggest creating a junction table which relates cities to their respective countries.  So, your three tables might look like this:

```
city (PK id, name, ...)
country (PK id, name, ...)
country_city (city_id, country_id)  PK (city_id -> city(id), country_id -> country(id))
```

With this design, you don't need to worry about the auto increment sequences in the `city` and `country` table.  Just let Postgres assign those values, and then just maintain the junction table using the correct values.

Comment: I don't understand your 3rd table concept. What I need to do is to have the same rows in both tables share the same id (esp because these rows have already been used in other tables), while new rows in table2 needing to have different ids

Comment: @Luffydude Unfortunately, you are completely missing the point of my answer.  Your city and country tables should be related via primary and foreign key relationships, _not_ via row sequence.

Comment: apologies if I wasn't clear, the sequence IS the primary key of table1, and I need non used sequence numbers to be the primary key of table2

Comment: Yes, this is basically how my answer would be working.  The two `id` columns, for the `city` and `country` tables, would be auto increment sequences.  Then the primary key of the junction table would be the combination of a value from each sequence.

Comment: But then I'd have a 3rd table and 2 of them already total over 200gb

Comment: Junction tables are typically pretty lean, because they just contain integer IDs.  Adding one isn't going to break your database.

Comment: Okay but i still wouldnt have anything to junction with since the point of this question is to create a meaningful pk id for the table2. It does not have a pk. I'm using the query I commented above

Comment: If you use an auto increment column, then the database takes care of the problem of generating the primary key.  You should generally _not_ be doing what you are suggesting, I think.